# Access Database Not Updating or Inserting or Deleting C# using Table Adapters and DataBinding

Tags: c#, ms-access, data-binding, datagridview, tableadapter

I am trying to update my Access File Using Table Adapter .
When i add the Data my DataGridview shows that data has been added or deleted 
But when I Check my access file it stays the same 
THere is no Compilation Error or No Excetion Error 
This is the Following Code
[This is the Image of the Data Grid View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqGvv.png)
....

```
  private void adminFlights_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'appData.Airline' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.airlineTableAdapter.Fill(this.appData.Airline);
        airlineBindingSource.DataSource = this.appData.Airline;

    }

 private void dataGridView2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {//TO delete data from Data Grid view
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You want TO Delete ?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                airlineBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
             }}}




   private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//this the Button i am using save the Data into acess using DatagridView

        try
        {
            dataGridView2.DataSource = airlineBindingSource.DataSource;

            airlineBindingSource.EndEdit();
            airlineTableAdapter.Update(this.appData.Airline);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }


  private void Add_flights_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            panel.Enabled = true;
            Airline_add.Focus();
            this.appData.Airline.AddAirlineRow(this.appData.Airline.NewAirlineRow());
            airlineBindingSource.MoveLast();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            airlineBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this code I don't see anything related to OleDb

Comment: I am sorry I have a bit misconception about it .. I know that i am binding the data.. I am using data grid and with that i am saving it on my acess database .. which is not happening

Comment: Does your adapter have insert and update commands set? If you close and re-open is new data shown on the grid? Does `AddAirlineRow` add a row in an Added state? There is too much going on that we cannot see so we cannot answer.

Comment: My 'AddFlight Adds the Data into the Data Grid View On Runtime 
but when i start the program again its all gone..
i used the link below to program the whole Code 
It had no Insert Statement 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uONQaT-nwls&t=1072s

Comment: There is also One thing that my access FILE **bin Folder** gets updated 
But not the Source file which i have given in my program 

When i restart the program The access file in Bin Folder Also resets back to the old version